# ActiveRecord Scope on Polymorphic Relationshps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models that have a polymorphic relationship as follows:

```
class DataSource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sourceable, polymorphic: true
end

class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :data_sources, as: :sourceable

  # For the sake of this example, I have place the scope here.
  # But I am going to put it in a Concern since Baz needs this scope as well.
  scope :bar_source_id, -> (id) do 
    joins(:data_sources)
    .where(data_sources: { source: 'bar', source_id: id })
    .first
  end
end


class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :data_sources, as: :sourceable
end
```

I want to be able to find a `Foo` record based on the `source_id` of the related `DataSource`. In otherwords, `Foo.bar_source_id(1)` should return a `Foo` record who's `data_sources` contains a record with `source: 'bar', source_id: 1`. However the scope on the `Foo` model does not work as I expected.

`Foo.bar_source_id(1)` returns the correct `Foo` record but if there is no `DataSource` with a `source_id` of `1` `Foo.all` is returned.

On the other hand `Foo.joins(:data_sources).where(data_sources: { source: 'bar', source_id: 1 }).first` will always return either the correct record or `nil` if no record exists. This is the behaviour I expected.

Why does this query work when I call it off of the model itself, but not when I include it in the model as a scope?

Edit:

I have a partial answer to my question. `.first` in the scope was causing a second query that loads all `Foo` records. If I remove `.first` I will get back an `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Why does `.first` behave differently in these two contexts?

Answer (score 0):

After digging around I found this: [ActiveRecord - "first" method in "scope" returns more than one record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649804/activerecord-first-method-in-scope-returns-more-than-one-record)

I assume the rationale here is that `scope` isn't meant to return a single record, but a collection of records.

I can get the results I need by adding a method `bar_source_id` instead of using a scope.

```
def self.bar_source_id(id)
  joins(:data_sources)
  .where(data_sources: { source: 'bar', source_id: id })
  .first
end
```